# How to isolate (audio) components supplied with the same battery?

Tags: batteries, noise

We built a very simple circuit out of prebuilt components: a battery, a signal generator, an amplifier, and a speaker. The signal generator (i.e. a Bluetooth player) and the amplifier are supplied with the same 12v battery.

[image: circuit]

The problem is that although the circuit works (mostly) as expected, one of the components (I guess it's the amplifier) generates a high frequency noise coming out of the speaker.

We just identified the following facts:

- Adding a resistor to cable (B) won't decrease the noise (even if the music is completely silenced)
- Supplying the signal generator from a separate battery makes the noise disappear
- Disconnecting cable (A) won't break the circuit, but increase the noise

Not sure whether this is enough informaion, but I wonder whether there is a way to make the noise disappear without adding an additional battery.

Comment: 1/ Do you know how much current the signal generator uses? 2/ can the signal generator run of a lower voltage (As you have an amplifier) (I am thinking of at adding a regulator or filter to the signal generator supply)

Comment: I would appreciate it if someone turned this into a comment (do not have sufficient privilege to comment yet). The symptoms you have posted make me suspect that the noise is coming from your power supply. When you used a separate power source for the signal generator, what was that power source? Can you try putting a simple low-pass filter on the output of the power supply? As for isolating audio components in general, this might help - http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Semiconductors/opto_53.php

Comment: Please describe your problem, there are probably better ways to solve this with EMI suppression

Comment: @Oldfart 1) 70 mA 2) no, both requires 12V, I tried to install a decouple capacitor, didn't work
http://www.capacitorguide.com/coupling-and-decoupling/

Comment: @Tri - The power source is a 12v battery. We used the same battery for that test - it made all noise disappear. Since removing cable (A) will not break the circuit (generated signal continues to come out of the speaker, I doubt an optocoupler would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with relatively expensive solution: adding a 12V to 12V isolating DC adapter between the battery and the signal generator. That way cable (A) was no longer connected with the common ground, therefore, the noise disappeared.